# Java based caching queue having enteries with predefined time to live

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, queue, guava

I need it in the following scenario:

1.Data are received continuously from network. 
2.The data received are added into Queue Buffer.

Data which is add in queue buffer will be having predefined TimeToLive.
If I am adding Data1 in queue it can live upto X seconds.

Guava provides time based cache but it's key based and is not ordered.For me ordering of the data when it's inserted in cache is important as I would want to poll and process the data.

If anyone knows of some existing library/cache api that may have ordered,time based eviction implementation please share.

Comment: Having minimal code examples and stripped down versions of your data structures might help to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly I had a similar problem and found guava to be insufficient regarding this point too.

Maybe you could store the data in simple queue and just store references to the items in the cache.
Using handlers on the reference cache you could be notified when they are expired and then manually remove the evicted items from data queue.

Comment: I was running a cleanup daemon thread in background.But this is a nice approach, using the callbacks handlers for eviction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to need *any* cache.

When pulling an entry, check if it's still alive and process or drop it. If you want to save memory, do some periodic culling (by pulling and filtering all elements).

**Misusing any cache can make it only worse:**

- additional memory and time overheads
- dependency on the exact eviction algorithm, where the cache is optimized for caching rather than evicting the way you want
- speed problem when removing in the order dictated by the cache from some random position of the queue (this can be done efficiently using a home brew double linked list, but that's another complication and memory waste).

Comment: Producer will be pumping the data in queue regardless whether the subscriber s up and running.If my subscriber is out of action say for X minutes and after coming up it has to immediately start processing the still alive object.    If I don't have time based eviction cache, subscriber has to clean up the dead objects before it can actually start processing still alive objects.

Comment: @Sara A cache is sort of `Map`, associating keys to values; this is not your case. Re-using the cache eviction functionality is probably harder (an surely less efficient) then making an own eviction (as you already did according to you comment to the other answer). Consider posting your code to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java).